# Can a react/javascript object child have a value and children at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, children

I believe I have seen examples of this that answer my question in the positive, but this seems very hard to search for and I cannot find it now.
Can a react/javascript object child have both a value and more children at the same time?

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do, where header would both a value for its own height, but also have children:

```
const height = {
    header: '100px' {
        icon: '20px',
        text: '25px'
    }
}
```

Comment: the inner object is not children, regardless the purpose of using it, but from code perspective, it's not for children, it's a value of type object, so in this example you are trying to pass two values to one key, one is string and one is object, I'd recommend you to spend some time reading more about objects in JS to know how to use it correctly

Comment: how do you know whether you want to access '100px' or the object ```{ icon: 20px, text: 25px}``` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. You could however try the following:

```
const height = {
    header: { data: '100px',
              inner: {icon: '20px', text: '25px'}
            } 
}
```

or

```
const height = {
    header: ['100px',
              {icon: '20px', text: '25px'}
            ]
}
```